# Microsoft Teams copy/paste exact highlighted text? Do not include message metadata

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard, microsoft-teams, plaintext

Microsoft Teams injects a bunch of annoying text when you try to copy/paste a highlighted message.

[image: Microsoft Teams Copy/Paste]

as you can see, I've highlighted the message text. I then copy/paste using the standard Mac keyboard shortcuts.

Pasting results in the text:

```
[1:41 PM] LastName, FirstName
this is the message text I have highlighted and copied
 angry 1
```

So rather than copy/paste the text I highlighted, the Microsoft Teams clipboard also includes the timestamp and name of the sender, the type and number of reactions to the message, and 2 blank lines.

This is incredibly annoying for copying and pasting, say, terminal commands out of the Team chat.

How can I disable this "feature"? I'm using Microsoft Teams version `1.5.00.17261` on macOS.

How can I copy/paste the plain text version of the text I highlight in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: In my Apps, paste always includes a Paste plain text option. Do you have that option?

Comment: See  https://twitter.com/microsoftteams/status/1459681532076072960?lang=en      Ctrl Shift V   to paste in plain text.

Comment: "paste plain text" won't work... additional text is being *copied* and will be in the output no matter how that pasted text is formatted.

Comment: Microsoft is stupid. There currently is no solution to this and I don't imagine they have any plans to fix this either

Comment: No application should be allowed to do this. This behavior should be prevented on the operating system level.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft being microsoft... Highlight the text from right to left rather than triple clicking :)

Comment: Left to right or right to left doesn't matter. As long as you just select the text itself en not the entire entry (what triple-click is doing).

Comment: Yes, apologies for not clarifying this!